# Convert data file to char array

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io, matrix

I have a file(res.txt) that looks like this:

```
a
na
na
a
a
a
na
```

I need to read this into a matrix and import into workspace. using `textscan` makes it a cell array. hence, `a(2)=n` not `na` . How do I import this file into a 1D matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt','rt')
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter',''); C = C{1};
fclose(fid);
```

Now each element of the cell array `C{i}` contains one line.

If you want an actual character matrix (padded with spaces of course), convert the cell array using:

```
arr = char(C);
```

Now each line is: `arr(i,:)` (might want to use `deblank` on that)

Comment: What is C? a cell matrix or a character matrix?

Comment: @MaxSteel: `C` is a cell array of strings of size 7-by-1. `arr` is a character matrix of size 7-by-2 (padded with spaces since MATLAB matrices cannot be jagged)